# Constructor map requires 'new' in Next js

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-leaflet

I'm using react-leaflet with nextjs. I have done all the prerequisites for the installation of react-leaflet module but when i load the page it shows the error Contructor Map requires 'new'. I have seen a similar problem for typescript, but i use regular javascript in my code.

The code is from the basic installation of react-leaflet component :

```
import { MapContainer, Marker, Popup, TileLayer, Map } from "react-leaflet";
import { icon } from "leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  mapCardContainer: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "690px",
    [theme.breakpoints.down("1655")]: {
      height: "390px",
      width: "100%",
    },
  },
}));

const HeatMap = () => {
  const [t, i18n] = useTranslation();
  const classes = useStyles();
  const ICON = icon({
    iconUrl: "/static/images/marker-icon.png",
    iconSize: [25, 41],
  });

  return (
    <>
      <MapContainer center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url='https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
        />
        <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
          <Popup>
            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </MapContainer>
    </>
  );
};

export default HeatMap;
```

Comment: Where's `Map` being used? Do you even need to import it from `react-leaflet`?

Comment: i just tried to use Map instead of MapContainer with no result